# How to access realm name in custom Keycloak theme

Tags: keycloak

We are creating a custom theme for our Keycloak implementation. We created a folder in themes and set it as default template which works fine. Now we want to edit the screen that is shown after a user was invited and updated their password and name. Currently it simply shows a success message without a link to the app or login page.
The ftl that is used for this screen is "\base\login\info.ftl" and the message is "accountUpdatedMessage" "base\login\messages". I can edit both of these and see the result but I can't find a way to access the current realm name (which I need for the link, as it is dynamic).

So now I have to questions:

1. In the info.ftl they use a parameter called "actionUri", how can I set this parameter including the realm name?
2. If I can't set the actionUri, is how can I access the realm name as a parameter for a message? I see that it's done in other messages, but I don't understand where this value needs to be set...?

Thank you!